# how can i supress error messages on a certain bloc of code in powershell

Tags: powershell, error-handling

I want to supress displaying error messages on a certain bloc of code in powershell.

I know that `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` supress error displaying, but it only goes with a cmd-let, in my case i have instructions dealing with variables and affecting some values so i can't use `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`

Here is an example of my code :

```
foreach ($sub in $subsites)
            {
                $subName=$sub.GetAttribute("name")
                $subDescription=$sub.get_InnerText()
                $subUrl=$sub.getAttribute("url")
                $subTerm=$term.CreateTerm($subName,1033) 
                $subTerm.SetDescription($subDescription, 1033) 
                $subTerm.CreateLabel("MOAD_SubTerm", 1033, $false) 
                $termStore.CommitAll()
            }
```

I want to hide errors **ONLY** for this part of the code , **not for the hole file**.

How can i do this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try changing the value of the `$ErrorActionPreference` variable:

```
$errpref = $ErrorActionPreference #save actual preference
$ErrorActionPreference = "silentlycontinue"
...
your code
...
$ErrorActionPreference = $errpref #restore prevuious preference
```